# PHP code not being executed

Tags: php, apache

I am new to PHP programming - and I'm trying to execute my first php test page. The problem is, that the php doesn't get executed (page returns php page content:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I did the following steps to enable Apache service (according to Apache readme file):

1. Extracted Apache server for 64bit windows from http://apachelounge.com to C:/ (default dir)
2. Checked configuration in .../conf/httpd.conf, default directory matches
3. Installed Apache as a service via "httpd.exe -k install" command in Win cmd prompt
4. Opened ApacheMonitor and started the Apache service from it

When I'm launching the php page, I copy the file to htdocs sub-folder. Then I open my browser (Firefox) and insert http://localhost/test.php

Comment: type http://localhost only, what get?

Comment: So you didnt yet install PHP from what you say. I suggest you uninstall what you have done and then install either WAMPServer or XAMPP as both these come with Apache PHP and MYSQL all installed with one click

Comment: WAMPServer did the job - thank you!